# Doing computations on lists inside data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I want to aggregate data frame `f` into a new data frame `g` so that the column `g$z` contains a **list** of all group-wise values from column `f$z`. At first sight, this seems to be working:

```
f = data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 1, 2), y=c(4, 4, 5, 6), z=c(11, 12, 13, 14))
g = aggregate(z ~ x + y, f, c)

  x y      z
1 1 4 11, 12
2 1 5     13
3 2 6     14
```

Now I want to do different computations on the lists in column `c` for all rows in the data frame and put the result in new columns in the same data frame. But this doesn't work!

```
g$m = sum(g$z)
g$n = g$z + 1

Error in sum(g$z) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

How can I work with lists inside a data frame cell like attempted above? Or is this simply un-R-like / impossible? If so, what is the correct approach?

**UPDATE**

My underlying goal is to do a lot of group-wise operations on all combinations of X and Y in the original data set. What options do I have for this in R in general?

1. Use `apply`. Pro: Everything in one table. Con: Complex table structure, can't use `sum` etc.
2. for(y), for(x), subset. Pro: Can do `sum` etc. directly. Con: Lots of code, and possibly slow.
3. Work in parallell w/original and aggregated table. Pro: Can do `sum` etc. Con: Data duplication.
4. Other options?

Comment: `sapply` for `g$m`, as below.  And `g$n <- relist(unlist(g$z) + 1, g$z)`

Answer (score 2):

*sum* and *Vectorization* doesn't apply to lists, you can simply use `sapply` and `lapply` for the task:

```
g$m <- sapply(g$z, sum)
g$n <- lapply(g$z, `+`, 1)

g
#  x y      z  m      n
#1 1 4 11, 12 23 12, 13
#2 1 5     13 13     14
#3 2 6     14 14     15
```

Or if you use `tidyverse`, you can use `map` + `mutate`:

```
g %>% mutate(m = map_dbl(z, sum), n = map(z, ~.x + 1))

#  x y      z  m      n
#1 1 4 11, 12 23 12, 13
#2 1 5     13 13     14
#3 2 6     14 14     15
```

Comment: Use `vapply`, not `sapply`.  `vapply` always returns a vector of the specified type with known dimensions. `sapply` can return a vector, an array, or a list, depending on the input.

Comment: @NathanWerth - The return structure depends more on `FUN` than it does `X`. Since `sum` will always return a length 1 numeric, `sapply` will in turn always return an atomic vector (provided `simplify = TRUE`).   `vapply` is faster though.

Comment: Using apply works! However I've updated the question to reflect how to best work with group-wise data in R in general.

Comment: @Rich You're right, the shape of `sapply`'s result is guaranteed when using `sum`.  I'm just making a note of "best general practice" for anyone reading your answer.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your update. But with dplyr, something like this `f %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise(m = sum(z), n = list(2*z), z = list(z)) %>% as.data.frame()` can help get the summaries done in one step.